# it's also the only place that you can get a decent meal

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

> I created the OASIS because I never felt at home in the real world. I just didn't know how to connect with the people there. I was afraid for all of my life right up until the day I knew my life was ending. Now, that was when I realized that, as terrifying and painful as reality can be, it's also the only place *that* you can get a decent meal.

(Transcription of [Ready Player One clip starting at 3:06](https://youtu.be/kve9w5LdxZY?t=186))

In [the last clause (starting at 3:41)](https://youtu.be/kve9w5LdxZY?t=221), does the italicized *that* sound natural?

> a. it's also the only place *that* you can get a decent meal.

How does (a) fare compared with (b) or (c)?

> b. it's also the only place *where* you can get a decent meal.

> c. it's also the only place you can get a decent meal.

Answer (score 1):

All three work well.  You can use "where" as the relativizer for a clause that describes a place.  And the relativizer can be omitted completely when the relative clause has an explicit subject ("you")

So these are all fine.  Using "Where" is perhaps the most formal. Using "that" is slightly more relaxed, and the fact that "reality" isn't a conventional "place" makes "that" a good choice.

Comment: Thanks. But according to a grammar book, _that_ in _This is much better than the place that we stayed last year._ is of questionable grammaticality. If you agree with this judgment, how would you distinguish the two cases? (The book says using _where_ instead of _that_ or even omitting _that_ would be grammatical.)

Comment: The grammar is correct, you may use "where" when referring to a place but it isn't mandatory.  Using "where" is slightly more formal. In the example in the question, the speaker is being *informal* and the "place" is  *reality*, so not a real place.  These facts favour the equally grammatical relativiser "that".

Comment: Are you saying that if _place_ is a real place, you can't use _that_ instead of _where_, but that if _place_ is not a real place, you can use _that_ instead of _where_?

Comment: No I'm saying that if *place* is a real place, you can use "that" or "where", but "where" might be more formal.  And if "place" is not actually a place then "that" might be chosen, especially in casual speech.

Comment: But in the example cited in the grammar book, _place_ refers to a real place, but the book says using _that_ there is of questionable grammaticality.

Comment: Well, like I said,  there are contexts in which "where" is preferred.  Perhaps there are some in which "that" is of questionable grammar.  But in the example in the question, "that" is not incorrect.

Comment: So how can you tell when it's correct and when it's not?